# How do I compare execution time of two queries is SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two similar queries and I want to compare time they take to execute. However I cant figure out what is the right way to get query execution time and also how do I compare them fairly if each time you run a query its time gets lower?

Comment: You could clear the sga, or bounce your database so it's 'cold'...or go thr other way and run the queries 10-100x each and avg the response times

Answer (score 2):

you can get an average execution times from the [v$sqlarea](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2129.htm#REFRN30259) view.  Replace with whatever sql text to find your query.  Note that the rows in v$sqlarea are transient. Average times are in units of microseconds.

```
select sql_text, executions,
       elapsed_time/executions average_exec_time, 
       cpu_time/executions  average_cpu_time 
from v$sqlarea 
where sql_text like 'SELECT blah blah FROM%'
```

Note that this is just a "ballpark" figure.